# What is the next number of the sequence?

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

What is the next number of this sequence?

> 827, 23, 11, 6, 3, ?

Comment: -1 for copying off a web page. Posting a puzzle that is published elsewhere, say, in a book or magazine, is fine -- users browsing the web for a puzzle to solve might not have that book or magazine. But I don't see the point in copying onto this web site a puzzle on another web site -- a user might just as easily come across it there as here. Besides, this puzzle (rot13) eryvrf ba gur hfr bs n cnegvphyne qvnyrpg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was easy, the answer is

> 5

Explanation  :

> 827 = eight hundred twenty seven : contains 23 characters
>  23 = twenty three : 11 characters
>  11 = eleven : 6 characters
>  6 = six : 3 characters
>  3 = three : 5 characters

Comment: Correct Answer..

Comment: This is also the very [first hit](http://www.pzzls.com/sequences_puzzle/solution.html) on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22827,+23,+11,+6,+3%22) (for me, at least) although that site lists the correct logic and wrong answer.